# Open/Reopen dialog regarding Finder keeps popping up?

Tags: finder, mojave

After upgrading to Mojave (10.14.4) Finder appears to crash producing the following dialog:

[image]

I've also noticed `.crash` files accumulating in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` regarding Finder since doing the upgrade.

Looking at these `.crash` files it appears Finder is crashing:

```
$ ls |grep Find.*.crash | wc -l
     388
```

Example `.crash` file:

```
$ more ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2019-05-05-105000_smingolelli.crash 
Process:               Finder [17433]
Path:                  /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
Identifier:            com.apple.finder
Version:               10.14.4 (1143.4.5)
Build Info:            Finder_FE-1143004005000000~4
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Finder [17433]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2019-05-05 10:49:44.583 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.4 (16P4507)
Anonymous UUID:        45606DD2-800B-B008-F8D7-C4E0D1D10A51

Sleep/Wake UUID:       EA3613C3-1281-4C1B-95C1-4380FA6BC430

Time Awake Since Boot: 36000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       31 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        5  Dispatch queue: TDesktopViewDataSource: Sort

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [17433]

VM Regions Near 0x18:
-->
    __TEXT                 000000010a179000-000000010a8d0000 [ 7516K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff337193bd CFBasicHashAddValue + 155
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3371fa76 CFDictionaryAddValue + 187
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff33748309 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff337480f2 CFBasicHashApply + 105
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff33748071 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 130
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3378a955 ___CFPrefsDeliverPendingKVONotificationsGuts_block_invoke + 289
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff33748309 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff337480f2 CFBasicHashApply + 105
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff33748071 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 130
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3378a7bc _CFPrefsDeliverPendingKVONotificationsGuts + 246
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3378a6c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3374ddd7 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 394
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3374db34 __CFRunLoopRun + 2772
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3374ce0e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 455
14  com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x00007fff32a399db RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
15  com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x00007fff32a39715 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 603
16  com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x00007fff32a394a6 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
17  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff30dd3ffb _DPSNextEvent + 965
18  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff30dd2d93 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
19  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff30dcceb0 -[NSApplication run] + 699
20  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff30dbc3f0 NSApplicationMain + 777
21  com.apple.finder                    0x000000010a17f9f1 0x10a179000 + 27121
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5fbc13d5 start + 1
...
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: "Crashed Thread:        5  Dispatch queue: TDesktopViewDataSource: Sort" mind adding thread 5 info ?

Answer (score 1):

Research this particular issue kept leading to this as one potential solution.

- [macOS 10.14 Mojave problems: how to fix them](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/macos-1014-mojave-problems-how-to-fix-them)
- [The last time you opened Finder, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6645839)

To find & delete the preferences file for Finder. This file is located here:

```
$ find ~/Library/Preferences -name com.apple.finder.plist -ls
18015144       48 -rw-------    1 smingolelli      staff               24369 May  5 19:50 /Users/smingolelli/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

You can delete it like so:

```
$ find ~/Library/Preferences -name com.apple.finder.plist -delete
```

Deleting this `.plist` file for Finder stopped Finder from continuing to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue (10.15.6) and removed com.apple.finder.plist with no effect.

Another suggestion, linked to Citrix, is here  : https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/case-of-the-macos-finder-non-stop-crashing/. I have tried it with no luck.

The only (quite unsatisfying) solution I have found is to use another account, transfer everything from the problematic account to it, and start again from there.

Then, in my case, the issue keeps on coming back (even in safe mode).